# Flickering lines in Grease Pencil Line Art (Eevee)

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, grease-pencil, lineart

So, I have added Line Art to a quite simple scene by adding a Stroke object and then setting a line art modifier.
I have adjusted the thickness and then baked the line art data.
Now, after I rendered the animation (it's also visible in viewport), some lines are extremely flickery:

[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMv2Ga-bWP8)

I don't even mind the light bleeding through that much, but the line flickering destroys the scene.

I went through all the settings I could think of, but could find anything. Do you have any idea on what might help?

[Scene file](https://stormbase.de/63_SpiralStaircase.blend); I've been using Blender 3.1.0 Beta; the problem also exists in 3.2.0 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by making sure there were no lines perfectly in front of one another from the cameras point of view.
Blender apparently freaks out if two lines fight to be in front.